# vPC between Cisco nexus 9236C and 9336C

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, vpc

I have a Nexus N9K-C9236C and I would like to add an other one to have redundancy with vPC fonctionnality (like describe [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/7-x/interfaces/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Interfaces_Configuration_Guide_7x/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Interfaces_Configuration_Guide_7x_chapter_01000.html)).

The point is my suppliers don't sell this model anymore because it has reach its EOL.

So the "new" model is the N9K-C9336C and I want to know if the vPC will works between these 2 models.

I didn't see any limitation in the Cisco documentation but my seller says me it's not possible...

If anyone had any information about this situation, I'll be interrested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, this can't be done.  The models have to be the same even if they're models in the same family.  Here's an answer from a Cisco forum entry on this topic and link to better explain and detail the requirements.

> No, it is not supported to have vPC between different families of
> Nexus, not even between different models from the same family:
>
> The switches in a vPC domain, the peer switches, must be of the same
> type. For example, you can connect a pair of Cisco Nexus 9300 series
> switches; but you cannot connect a Cisco Nexus 9300 series switch to a
> Cisco Nexus 9500 series switch within a vPC domain.

> vPC peer switches
> must also be of the same type. For example, you can connect a pair of
> Cisco Nexus 9300-EX switches, but you cannot connect a Cisco Nexus
> 9300-EX switch to a Cisco Nexus 9300-FX switch in a vPC domain. You
> can find more details about vPC in the config guide (where the above
> bullets are also present).

[vPC Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/93x/interfaces/configuration/guide/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-93x/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-93x_chapter_01000.html)